# Facebook fan page canvas source?

Tags: facebook, fbml, fbjs

Im trying to understand how to learn reading the source of a facebook fan page. So far, I can only get the layout displayed while viewing the source.

Here is an example: If you go here:
http://www.facebook.com/pages/See-oho-nieps-YothG-RRofiLe/106340746065367#!/pages/Milton-Keynes-United-Kingdom/IF-MR-BEAN-WAS-IN-AVATAR-HE-WOULD-LOOK-LIKE-THIS/302690570115

That canvas page requires you to be a fan of the page. This is done with:

content here

My question is, why cant I find the FB:visible code in the source of that page? I would be grateful for any guidance!

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because the FBML is interpreted server side, so if it output the markup their parser would have to be Javascript based, causing a greater risk to security (?) and slowing the process down entirely.

I'm not too familiar with it though, I must be honest.